SQLDescribeParam returning wrong information (always type SQL_VARCHAR)
I am trying to use the SQLDescribeParam() function with UnixODBC and MariaDB.  No matter what I try with the parameter, it always returns SQL_VARCHAR.
My table has one column USERID defined as CHAR(20).
My SELECT statement is:
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERID = ?

Here is my code and the results:
#include <iostream>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
    
std::string describeNullable(const SQLSMALLINT &value) {
    switch(value) {
    case SQL_NO_NULLS: return "SQL_NO_NULLS";
    case SQL_NULLABLE: return "SQL_NULLABLE";
    case SQL_NULLABLE_UNKNOWN: return "SQL_NULLABLE_UNKNOWN";
    default:
        return std::to_string(value);
    }
}

std::string describeDataType(const SQLSMALLINT &value) {
    switch(value) {
    case SQL_UNKNOWN_TYPE: return "SQL_UNKNOWN_TYPE";
    case SQL_CHAR: return "SQL_CHAR";
    case SQL_NUMERIC: return "SQL_NUMERIC";
    case SQL_DECIMAL: return "SQL_DECIMAL";
    case SQL_INTEGER: return "SQL_INTEGER";
    case SQL_SMALLINT: return "SQL_SMALLINT";
    case SQL_FLOAT: return "SQL_FLOAT";
    case SQL_REAL: return "SQL_REAL";
    case SQL_DOUBLE: return "SQL_DOUBLE";
    case SQL_DATETIME: return "SQL_DATETIME";
    case SQL_VARCHAR: return "SQL_VARCHAR";
    case SQL_TYPE_DATE: return "SQL_TYPE_DATE";
    case SQL_TYPE_TIME: return "SQL_TYPE_TIME";
    case SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP: return "SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP";
    default:
        return std::to_string(value);
    }
}

int main() {
    // set environement
    SQLHANDLE env;
    auto ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
    ret = SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    // get connection
    SQLHANDLE conn;
    ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &conn);
    std::string inConnectString{"DRIVER=MariaDB;UID=***;PWD=***;database=clientserver"};
    SQLCHAR* outConnectString = new SQLCHAR[512];
    SQLSMALLINT outStringLen{0};
    ret = SQLDriverConnect(conn,SQL_NULL_HANDLE, reinterpret_cast<SQLCHAR*>(const_cast<char*>(inConnectString.c_str())),
            inConnectString.length(),outConnectString, 512, &outStringLen,SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    delete [] outConnectString;
    outConnectString = nullptr;

    // set statement
    SQLHANDLE stmt;
    ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, conn, &stmt);
    std::string sqlstmt{"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERID = ?"};
    ret = SQLPrepare(stmt,reinterpret_cast<SQLCHAR*>(const_cast<char*>(sqlstmt.c_str())), sqlstmt.length());

    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
        SQLSMALLINT parmNum{1};
        SQLSMALLINT dataType{0};
        SQLULEN parameterSize{0};
        SQLSMALLINT decimalDigits{0};
        SQLSMALLINT nullable{SQL_NULLABLE};
        ret = SQLDescribeParam(stmt, parmNum, &dataType, &parameterSize,
                 &decimalDigits, &nullable);
        if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
            std::cout << "Parameter: " << parmNum << " Type: " << describeDataType(dataType);
            std::cout << " Size: " << parameterSize << " Decimal digits: " << decimalDigits;
            std::cout << " Nullable: " <<describeNullable(nullable) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

Here is my output:
Parameter: 1 Type: SQL_VARCHAR Size: 25165824 Decimal digits: 0 Nullable: SQL_NULLABLE_UNKNOWN

I was expecting to get back a parameter type of SQL_CHAR and a length of 20.
Note:  These are other things I have tried:

SQLBIndParameter() before the prepare, and still get the same answer.

Changing the data type of USERID, I've tried char, tinyint, timestamp, and keep getting back SQL_VARCHAR.



Your describeDataType() function has a typo, it is returning "SQL_DATETIME" for both SQL_DATETIME and SQL_VARCHAR types. Your column is CHAR(20) which should be reported as SQL_CHAR, but maybe your parameter is actually being treated as SQL_VARCHAR instead? What is the actual numeric value of dataType?

Your typo in describeDataType may be one good reason to use macros.  #define CHECK_TYPE(x) case x : return #x.  Then the switch statement would be switch(value) { CHECK_TYPE(SQL_UNKNOWN_TYPE); CHECK_TYPE(SQL_DATETIME); CHECK_TYPE(SQL_VARCHAR);. etc.  In other words, you are typing in the value just once per value.

Thank you.  I'm an idiot, but that doesn't explain the now they are all sql_varchar. The underlying datatype never changes from 12.  I would expect it to change if the type of USERID changed.  But it doesn't seem to.

Changed question per above comment. I suspect the ODBC types of CHAR doesn't match to the protocol types and VARCHAR is the closest match. Unsure why the size didn't map.

@TomDavidson I haven't done ODBC programming in years, but from what I remember, the SQLGetFunctions can be used to determine if support for SQLDescribeParam exists.   Look at the SQL_API_SQLDESCRIBECOL flag.  Maybe you should write a function that goes through all the flags, and logs exactly what is and is not supported by the MariaDB ODBC driver (or any ODBC driver for that matter).

MariaDB doesn't provide metadata information for parameters, therefore the information is not available and SQLDescribeParam always returns SQL_VARCHAR as default.
See here: MariaDB Connector/ODBC Source Code
